# Hebrew string reverse printing

Tags: php, right-to-left, hebrew

I trying to `echo` 
this line:

```
$mother_name = "סבטלנה ואסילבנה"; 
echo strrev($mother_name);
```

result is: `�נבליסאו� �נלטבס�`

What is wrong? Where from I getting this `�` symbol. 
and when I trying to `echo` single char from the string
I getting also `�` for example `$mother_name[0]`

Comment: I think PHP is having difficulties with the charset of the Hebrew characters, I might be wrong though..

Comment: You shouldn't be reversing the string, you should be using an RTL mark for embedding hebrew in otherwise LTR documents. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark

Comment: Sadly, pretty much all the str* functions are unsuitable for multibyte encodings. They operate on single bytes, not characters.

Comment: Not sure whether it's helpful, but I've just tested it with Scala (uses same JVM strings as Java), it prints סבטלנה ואסילבנה in forward direction and הנבליסאו הנלטבס if the string is reversed. Afair php's strings are rather byte arrays that do not cope with unicode very well...

Comment: Actually, that string is totally fine. What are you trying to do to it and why?

Comment: @bobblebubble you also cannot simply reverse a UTF string like that, if it contains combining marks, diacritics, or other similar codepoints it's going to corrupt the content of the string.

Comment: I have to reverse string. I writing code where I using reversing string

Comment: @bobblebubble working. write answer i will mark it as right , thanks

Answer (score 5):

The marked duplicate answer is also wrong for the same reason that @bubblebobble's comment is wrong. You cannot simply reverse the order of individual code points and expect a sane string to come out the other side.

The intl library provides a sane method around this via `IntlBreakIterator::createCharacterInstance()` which interprets coherent *sequences* of code points:

```
function utf8_strrev($input) {
    $it = IntlBreakIterator::createCharacterInstance('he_IL.utf8');
    $it->setText($input);

    $ret = '';
    $prev = 0;
    foreach ($it as $pos) {
        $ret = substr($input, $prev, $pos - $prev) . $ret;
        $prev = $pos;
    }
    return $ret;
}

function naieve_utf8_strrev($input) {
    return implode("", array_reverse(preg_split('//u', $input)));
}

$tests = [
    "test",
    "סבטלנה ואסילבנה",
    "nai\xcc\x88ve fail"
];

foreach($tests as $test) {
    var_dump(
        $test,
        naieve_utf8_strrev($test),
        utf8_strrev($test)
    );
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
string(4) "test"
string(4) "tset"
string(4) "tset"

string(29) "סבטלנה ואסילבנה"
string(29) "הנבליסאו הנלטבס"
string(29) "הנבליסאו הנלטבס"

string(12) "naïve fail"
string(12) "liaf ev̈ian"
string(12) "liaf evïan"
```

and I *still* think that trying to reverse a hebrew string like this is the wrong way to to go if all you want is a left-to-right display of hebrew text. You should be using UTF8 LRO/RLO and PDF marks to switch the direction.

**Edit:** Finally tracked down the correct codepoints.

```
function utf8_force_ltr($input) {
    $LRO = "\xe2\x80\xad"; // left-right override
    $PDF = "\xe2\x80\xac"; // pop directional formatting
    return $LRO . $input . $PDF;
}

var_dump($test, utf8_force_ltr($test));
```

Output:

```
string(29) "סבטלנה ואסילבנה"
string(35) "‭סבטלנה ואסילבנה‬"
```

Comment: Thank you for showing. you think this won't work either [`preg_match_all('/\X/u', $input, $out)`...](https://eval.in/981083)? Actually I thought, that the empty regex would match between each `\X` which matches any number of Unicode characters that form an extended Unicode sequence.

Comment: @bobblebubble the `\X` does seem to work. And it's not that your original solution doesn't properly match multi-byte UTF8 sequences [it does], it's that a single on-screen glyph may be composed of several sequences whose order must be preserved even when reversing or otherwise modifying the string. That's why the diacritic is applied to the wrong character when reversed using the naieve method.